# Unable to update Flash

Tags: windows-7, flash

I think this issue has been going on for over a month now.

I boot my PC and the Adobe Updater tells me to download a new version of Flash. It sends me to https://get3.adobe.com/flashplayer/update/plugin/ with the following information visible:

> Version 11.9.900.152
>
> Your system:
>
> Windows, English

The *Update Now* button simply links to http://www.adobe.com/

[image: screenshot with freehand circles]

- I've cleared my cache, that didn't help.
- The *Are you an IT manager or OEM* links me to a page where I can either *Apply to distribute Flash Player* or *Download Adobe Flash Player*, the latter just sends me back to where I came from.
- I've uninstalled and rebooted, went to the Adobe website and clicked *Adobe Flash Player* under the *Download* menu. The *Install now* button again links me to http://www.adobe.com/
- *Need Flash Player for a different computer?* sends me to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ and the *Download now* button is greyed out and unclickable.

How can I update?

Comment: So far you've just stated what you see, but not included what you've tried or where you're getting stuck.  Have you cover the basics?   Have you tried clearing the browser's cache?  Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling Flash?  Have you tried using the full installer (the "Are you an IT manager or OEM" link should help you get that)?

Comment: @techie007 I'd say I'm stuck at the updating part. I haven't tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I'll do that now. Regarding the other two questions, I've updated my post.

Comment: @techie007 I've uninstalled and now I cannot install Flash at all, see the edit.

Comment: What version of Flash do you currently have installed?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot after uninstalling it?  BTW: If you "apply to distribute flash player" you can get your hands on the full installer.  You just have to fill that form out to get it, not pay money or anything. ;)

Comment: `The Update Now button simply links to http://www.adobe.com/` Does it actually *link* to the Adobe home (i.e., you see that URL when hovering over it), or does it *go* there when you click it? I just checked it and when I hover over the button, it links to `https://get3.adobe.com/flashplayer/download/?installer=Flash_Player_11_for_Other_Browsers&os=Windows%207&browser_type=KHTML&browser_dist=Chrome…` It also goes there when I click it.

Comment: @Synetech It actually went to that page when clicking on it. I've been able to solve it though, see my answer.

Comment: Ah okay. So it showed the correct URL when hovering but got redirected when you clicked it by Ghostery?

Comment: @Synetech No, it showed `http://www.adobe.com/` and also went there. On the page Johntor linked to, Ghostery was hiding the dropdowns on the left.

Comment: If it was actually showing `www.adobe.com` when you hovered, the Ghosery was actually *modifying* the page (though that is a pretty odd and un-helpful modification to make).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the issue was the Ghostery addon for Firefox. Pausing the blocking gives me a proper URL to download the installer.

On http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ a few dropdowns appeared after pausing the blocking letting me pick an OS and a version.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the Flash installer from the [Flash Player - Different Versions (http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/)](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) page.

Make sure to select your OS and browser from the list.

Comment: I was about to add (I've just rebooted), I had found that page but the button is greyed out and I cannot click it.

Comment: Did you select the correct version on the left?

Comment: See my answer, apparently Ghostery was blocking that part. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Ok let us know the result